# how can we generate wsu:Id in soap request xml using java

Tags: soap, ws-security, wss4j

Please advise how can we generate  dynamic wsu:Id in soap request xml.

```
 <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-C68ABF4EC1E628F5B5143638245038886955">
                <wsu:Created>2015-07-08T19:07:30.388Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-07-08T19:12:30.388Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
```

Java code :

```
     private Element addTimestamp(Element wsSecurityHeaderElement)
                    throws SOAPException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
                /if (false == this.addTimestamp) {
                    return null;
                }/
                Document document = wsSecurityHeaderElement.getOwnerDocument();
                Element timestampElement = document.createElementNS(WSU_NAMESPACE,
                        "wsu:Timestamp");
                timestampElement.setAttributeNS(WSU_NAMESPACE, "wsu:Id", "TS");
            // hard coded  ts needs to be removed
                Attr idAttr = timestampElement.getAttributeNodeNS(WSU_NAMESPACE, "Id");
                timestampElement.setIdAttributeNode(idAttr, true);
                    Element createdElement = document.createElementNS(WSU_NAMESPACE,
                        "wsu:Created");
                DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
                GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                Date now = new Date();
                gregorianCalendar.setTime(now);
                gregorianCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = datatypeFactory
                        .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
                createdElement.setTextContent(xmlGregorianCalendar.toXMLFormat());
                timestampElement.appendChild(createdElement);
```

`Element expiresElement = document.createElementNS(WSU_NAMESPACE,
                    "wsu:Expires");
            Date expiresDate = new Date(now.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 5);
            gregorianCalendar.setTime(expiresDate);
            xmlGregorianCalendar = datatypeFactory
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
                  expiresElement.setTextContent(xmlGregorianCalendar.toXMLFormat());
            timestampElement.appendChild(expiresElement);
            wsSecurityHeaderElement.appendChild(timestampElement);
            return timestampElement;
        } </code>`

Comment: There are utilities that can generate the client side stubs/classes for you. It's been a while I did this. Have you check something like wsdl.exe?

Comment: Can you please share  useful url to the above requirement?

Comment: Did you add the wsu:Id="TS-C68ABF4EC1E628F5B5143638245038886955" ? and what is the C68ABF4EC1E628F5B5143638245038886955 part ?